# asp.net core app not serving ApiController route path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-apicontroller

My asp.net core web application is not serving the ApiController route I have setup, however it used to work but I didn't change anything so idk why its not working now.

When I navigate to https://localhost:5001/api/Demo; it returns me to my sites homepage instead of running the action and displaying the data. the url in the address bar does change to …:5001/api/Demo, but does not display the data.

```cs
    // controller

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public string Index(string result)
        {
            return "test string";
        }
    }
```

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "api/{controller=Demo}/{action=Index}/{result?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

==============================================

UPDATE: add configure method from startup class

Comment: Please share the `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` methods

Comment: I added the methods